# Javascript check for duplicates and add the duplicate id's

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following arrays

```
const prod = [
  {name:'Test1',vals:[12]},
  {name:'Test1', vals:[14]},
  {name:'Test2', vals:[19]}
   //other array items
 ]
```

What am  trying to do is to combine both Test1 into one vals array so that the final array will have

```
 const finalprod = [
  {name:'Test1',vals:[12,14]},
  {name:'Test2', vals:[19]}
   //other array items
 ]
```

SO i have tried

```
    prod.forEach(item=>{
      //check if name is contained in the array -am stuck here
   });
```

Am stuck on how to proceed. How do i proceed to  get the final array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce` instead of `forEach`, look for the item in the accumulator, if it exists, combine the vals with the current element's, otherwise just push it to the accumulator :

```js
const prod = [
  {name:'Test1',vals:[12]},
  {name:'Test1', vals:[14]},
  {name:'Test2', vals:[19]}   
 ]

const finalprod = prod.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const ndx = acc.findIndex(e => e.name === curr.name);

  if (ndx > -1)
    acc[ndx].vals = [...acc[ndx].vals, ...curr.vals];
  else
    acc.push(curr);

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(finalprod);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```js
const prod = [
  {name:'Test1',vals:[12]},
  {name:'Test1', vals:[14]},
  {name:'Test2', vals:[19]}
 ]


const prodDictionary = prod.reduce(
  (acc, {name, vals}) => {
    if (acc[name] === undefined) {
      acc[name] = [];
    }
    acc[name].push(...vals);
    return acc;
  },
  {}
);

const finalProd = Object.entries(prodDictionary)
  .map((name, vals) => ({name, vals}));

console.log(finalProd);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and `Map`

- Loop over the array use `name` as key
- If the key is already present in `Map` update it's value by appending current value to it
- If not present add current value as initial value to `Map` with current key

```js
const prod = [{name:'Test1',vals:[12]},{name:'Test1', vals:[14]},{name:'Test2', vals:[19]}]

let final = prod.reduce((op,{name,vals}) => {
  if(op.has(name)){
    op.set(name, {name, val:op.get(name).vals.concat(vals) })
  } else{
    op.set(name, {name,vals} )
  }
  return op
},new Map)

console.log([...final.values()])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a map of the names and their values, and [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform it to your desired shape. Additional comments in code.

```js
const prod = [{name:'Test1',vals:[12]},{name:'Test1', vals:[14]},{name:'Test2', vals:[19]}];
 
//Combine the values into an object, e.g. { Test1: [12,14], Test2: [19] }
const hash = prod.reduce((out, {name,vals}) => ({  //for each item in array
  ...out,                                          //append to existing map
  [name]: (out[name] || []).concat(vals)           //combine like names
}), {});

//Transform above obj into the desired shape
const result = Object.keys(hash).map(key => ({     //for each key
  name: key,                                       //set "name" to the key name
  vals: hash[key]                                  //and "vals" to the associated value
}));
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object to merge the names values and then turn it into your desired array

```js
const prod = [{
    name: 'Test1',
    vals: [12]
  },
  {
    name: 'Test1',
    vals: [14]
  },
  {
    name: 'Test2',
    vals: [19]
  },
];

const ret = Object.entries(prod.reduce((tmp, x) => {
  tmp[x.name] = (tmp[x.name] || []).concat(x.vals);

  return tmp;
}, {})).map(([x, y]) => ({
  name: x,
  vals: y,
}));

console.log(ret);
```